# WKWebKit: No dataDetectorTypes parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview, webkit

In `UIWebView`, it was fairly easy to add `UIDataDetectorTypes` to a view:

```
myUIWebView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypePhoneNumber;
```

And so on. However, `WKWebView` does not seem to have a similar property. [This](http://nshipster.com/wkwebkit/) reference mentions that it has moved to the `WKWebViewConfiguration` property at `myWebKitView.configuration`, but both the [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebViewConfiguration_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/WKWebViewConfiguration) and the headers themselves make no reference to `dataDetectorTypes`.

I'm currently trying to migrate an app from using `UIWebView` to `WKWebView`, and this app currently has user-configurable `UIDataDetectorTypes`. So, is there any way to implement this using the provided API, or would I have to write my own code to parse the HTML?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The cited article has been updated to reflect changes in the API between iOS 8 betas. As of 8.0.1, there is no `dataDetectorTypes` property on `WKWebView`, with no other comparable public API.

Until it's added back into the class, you'd have to implement this yourself with [NSDataDetector](http://nshipster.com/nsdatadetector/), or resign yourself to using `UIWebView`.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Do you have any thoughts on how such a property would be implemented? I was going to use `evaluateJavaScript:completionHandler:` to get the HTML of the web page on load, and then apply an `NSDataDetector` to the text, but I'm not sure if that's an optimal method.

Comment: We need to write a WKWebView extension for this and make it available on GitHub.

Comment: In iOS10 WKWebViewConfiguration has property "dataDetectorTypes"

Answer (score 26):

Actually WKwebView doesn't have a **dataDetectorTypes** property. But In iOS 10 **WKWebViewConfiguration** has.

Try the following code snippet.

```
WKWebViewConfiguration *theConfiguration = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
theConfiguration.dataDetectorTypes = WKDataDetectorTypeNone;

WKWebView *webView = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:_someFrame configuration:theConfiguration];
```

This will work only from iOS10 onwards.

Comment: this is working fine we take WKWebView using code. .but what if we take wkwebview in xib directly ?  not found any method to set configuration.

Comment: @Hitarth there is data detector settings in xib.

Comment: @ParagBafna . Thanks got it

Answer (score 5):

You can find in the storyboard attribute inspector

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

`WKWebView` data detectors can be set in `WKWebViewConfiguration`. Swift version:

```
let webViewCofig = WKWebViewConfiguration()
webViewCofig.dataDetectorTypes = [.address]
webView = WKWebView(frame: view.frame, configuration: webViewCofig)
```

Valid options are phoneNumber, link, address, calendarEvent, trackingNumber, flightNumber, lookupSuggestion and all. Pass empty `[]` to set to none.

Answer (score 1):

The property dataDetectorTypes has been added to WKWebViewConfiguration in iOS10.

The options are phoneNumber, link, address, calendarEvent, trackingNumber, flightNumber, lookupSuggestion and all.

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround for supporting phone number detector in WKWebView would be to apply **regex checker in javascript** via *WKUserScript*

```
NSString *jScript = @"document.getElementById(\"main\").innerHTML.replace(/[\+\d]{1}[\d]{2,4}[\s,][\d\s-\\(\\),]{7,}/g, \"<a href=\"tel:\$&\">\$&</a>\")";

WKUserScript *wkUScript = [[WKUserScript alloc] initWithSource:jScript injectionTime:WKUserScriptInjectionTimeAtDocumentEnd forMainFrameOnly:YES];
WKUserContentController *wkUController = [[WKUserContentController alloc] init];
[wkUController addUserScript:wkUScript];

WKWebViewConfiguration *wkWebConfig = [[WKWebViewConfiguration alloc] init];
wkWebConfig.userContentController = wkUController;

wkWebV = [[WKWebView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame configuration:wkWebConfig];
```